# How can I override the values of 1 column in a big dataframe using a small second dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a Pandas dataframe (`donations_df`) that contains thousands of donations. Each donation row has *many* columns, but the two key ones for my question are:

- A `recipient_id` column indicating who received the donation
- An `office` column indicating what legislative office the recipient holds.

Some of the values of the `office` column in `donations_df` are outdated, and I want to replace/override them.

So I have a second, much smaller dataframe (`overrides_df`). It contains the preferred office names I want to use. It has only a few rows (one for each recipient). For example:

```
| recipient_id | office             | 
| ------------ | ------------------ |
| 3839314      | Governor           |
| 24811446     | Secretary of State |
| 12733609     | Auditor            |
| 6676482      | Attorney General   |
```

What is the proper way to join/merge/update this?

What I want to happen is that for each donation in `donations_df`, if that donation's `recipient_id` exists in `overrides_df`, then then the donation would pick up the new `office` value from `overrides_df`

What is the proper way to join/merge/update these two to achieve that result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for recipient_id, office in override_df.values:
    donations_df.loc[donations_df["recipient_id"] == recipient_id, "office"] = office
```

However, you should use a [reference table](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_table) to avoid this problem!